# local classes c-ism

Tags: c++

Only first pair of values output on running this program seem correct, the others don't. What is going on?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class a
{
    public:
        class b
        {
            public:
                a* parent;
                void test()
                {
                    std::cout<<parent->value<<std::endl;
                }
        } b1;
        unsigned long value;
        a()
        {
            b1.parent = this;
            value = 2;
        }
        void go()
        {
            value++;
            b1.test();
        }
};

int main()
{
    {
        a a1;
        a1.go();
        std::cout<<a1.value<<std::endl;
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    {
        a a1; a1 = a();
        a1.go();
        std::cout<<a1.value<<std::endl;
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
    {
        std::vector<a> a1; a1.push_back(a());
        a1.at(0).go();
        std::cout<<a1.at(0).value<<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting?  Why are you expecting it?  What are you getting?

Comment: , = new line. I'm expecting. 3, 3, , 3, 3, , 3, 3. I'm getting (run the program to see this) 3, 3, , 2, 3, , 2, 3. The 2, 3 results are wrong and are occuring due to the way a1 is constructed, however I don't know why and I do need to be able to construct in this way.

Comment: These are not local classes they are *nested* classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a copy ctor and assignment operator for type 'a'.  When copying or assigning objects, you consequently don't properly update their b1.parent.  Instead, the b1.parent values point to a different 'a' object than their real parent.

To see this problem in action, use this in your existing code:

```
void go() {
  value++;
  std::cout << (this == b1.parent ? "as expected\n" : "uh-oh\n");
  b1.test();
}
```

To fix it, modify class a:

```
 a() : b1 (this), value (2) {}  // a change from your default ctor
 a(a const &x) : b1 (this), value (x.value) {}
 a& operator=(a const &x) {
   value = x.value;
   return *this;
 }
```

And modify class b (necessarily to use the ctor initializer as I do above):

```
 b(a *parent) : parent (parent) {}
```

Comment: I upvoted @BlueRaja's comment, but actually it's wrong (as well as the code in the answer). You need to do `{ b1.parent = this; }` in the body, or else modify `class b`.

Comment: I can't remember being more confused. This is fantastic but really I need to be able to understand why it works. I cant see yet why my original dosn't. Also I have tried yours and get "error C2535: 'a::a(void)' : member function already defined or declared" on the 2nd of the three constructors.

Comment: @alan2here: That ctor replaces your existing default ctor.  Adding it without removing your existing ctor will give the error you describe.

Comment: ty, so there are two constructors in 'a' and one in 'b'. I changed 'a(a const &x) : b1 (this), value (x.value) {}' to 'a() : b1(this) {value = 2;}', this is safe?

Comment: @alan2here: Yes; read up on "constructor initializers" (sometimes called either "constructor initializer lists" or "initializer lists").  Also read up on the Rule of Three.  Really, class b should have a copy ctor and assignment op too, but they should be private (with no definition) just to make sure they are never used.

Comment: Reading thease things now. This line 'a(a const &x) : b1 (this), value (x.value) {}' refers to value. Do I need to expand it if I add more things to 'a'?

Comment: @alan2here: Data members need to be initialized in the ctor, yes.  Read up on "constructor initializers".  What [book](http://tinyurl.com/so-cxxbooks) are you using?

Comment: I am learning C++ at UNI but havn't gone into this much detail on thease things. I wouldn't imagine trying to use for example 'value' after the class has been constructed and before 'value' has been assigned a value. It was just confusing due to the similar constructors. I could ofc have another function that sets class wide things like 'value' and is called by both constructors.

Comment: I see now that in the latter two examples in main of my program I'm using a copy assignment operator both in the 2nd example 'a1 = a();' and in the 3rd example with the std::vector but thats not used for the first where the value of 'a' is from 'a a1;' and that's why the three examples that appear to be very similar behave differently?

Comment: @alan2here: Yes, exactly that, except that vector uses the copy ctor instead of copy assignment.

Comment: 'b(a *p) {parent = p;}' works just as well as well for b's constructor. I can see what 'a() : b1(this) {value = 2;}' does as well now.

Comment: @alan2here: For some types (such as ints and pointers) you can use assignment in the body of the ctor instead of initialization, but I have found it better to prefer initialization whenever possible.

Comment: Ahh yes, commenting out the copy constructor only breaks the vector example, and yes, but oh well, it wouldn't be C++ else. Superb :¬) I understand sufficently now.